# Directory.Build.props not working when solution contains Framework and Core projects

Tags: c#, .net-core, version

I want all the projects within a solution to share the same version number.  If I add a Directory.Build.props file at the root of the solution, it copies the file to each project as expected.  While all the projects will build fine, I get a "publish" error on the Core projects.  It says:

Directory.Build.props could not be loaded. '', hexadecimal value 0x1A, is an invalid character. Line 5, position 11

Line 5, position 11 is the end of the file.

I believe this is the end-of-file marker.  If, however, I create the same Directory.Build.props file in the root of the Core project, it's fine.  The issue is "where" I create the file.

All the other projects (Framework 4.7.1) publish fine with the Directory.Build.props file created in the root of the solution.

I know I could change the folder structure of my solution so Core projects are in one folder, and framework projects are in another.  Then create a separate Directory.Build.props file for each "type" of project, but that's a hassle.  Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Why not put the version attribute(s) in one file e.g. Version.cs, and reference that file using the "**Add As link**" drop down option in the "**Add existing item...**" window? this way you have the version only in one file

[image]